# AWS Glue with DynanoDB and high cardinality maps

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

We have DynanoDB table that contains an attribute with high cardinality Map. It's essentially a dict[str, Any] where keys are UUID like object.

This causes high cardinality because UUIDs are mostly unique and rarely reused. When we load that DynamoDB table with AWS Glue then the DynamicFrame tries to examine the schema of the data and eventually crashes.

We load the DynamicFrame with

```
glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.export": "ddb",
        "dynamodb.s3.bucket": f"aws-glue-assets-{aws_account_id}-{aws_region}",
        "dynamodb.s3.prefix": "temporary/ddbexport/",
        "dynamodb.tableArn": f"arn:aws:dynamodb:{aws_region}:{aws_account_id}:table/tablename",
        "dynamodb.simplifyDDBJson": True,
    },
    transformation_ctx="node_read_datatable",
)
```

and this seems to analyse the table structure on the go.

Is there any way how to disable data analysis or load the data from DynamoDB without DynamicFrame, do some pivoting like marshalling dict -> list and then loading it into the DynamicFrame?

Or is it possible to override some data types with type hints?